# What does &inline in a url mean?

Tags: visualforce, parameters

I am having a VF page in a pagelayout and there is a outputlink in that Vfpage which calls another VF page. This VF page url is appended with `&inline=1`.

What does this `&inline=1` mean. I can see that the headers are missing on that page.
Is there a way to remove them out ?

Thanks

Comment: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Avoid-URL-parameter-inline-1/td-p/464697              Following discussion helped me to replace inline=1

Answer (score 1):

There's two options.

**First**, if you want to use an outputLink with an `action` attribute and a serverside function that returns a PageReference, there seems to be no supported way to turn the &inline part off.

One workaround that is mentioned is to let the page render and then, with Javascript, open a page without the inline part. Ugly, but it works. Set this piece of script just before the closing `</apex:page>` tag.

```
<script>
   var url = location.href;
   var match = url.match(/inline=1/);
   if (match != null) { 
      var newUrl = url.replace(/inline=1/, '');
      window.top.location=newUrl;
   }
</script>
```

**Second**, you could start using a simple `<apex:outputLink>` without an `action` attribute, but simply using a value that creates a direct URL. Like so

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.somePage}?id={!someObject.Id}" target="_top">click here</apex:outputLink>
```